# How to create a neo4j graph database within a java application

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to write a java application which gets the values and information from user and creates the graph database with neo4j,my question:

how should I create a neo4j graph database within my java application?

what tools should I use?

I read neo4j tutorials,but they were about creating a database first and query it from the application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Embedded neo4j, please see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded.html
Otherwise take a look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-rest.html and/or http://www.neo4j.org/develop/drivers if you wish to use things such as Spring Data

Comment: with these can I build a database from the java application,from the scratch?

Comment: Yes, for sure! It's how I built my first java-neo4j application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Neo4j library in your project I would suggest to first add the relative Maven dependency. Then, for the creation of a new database, just use this line:

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH)
```

If the database doesn't already exists, it will be created. Finally you should call

```
db.shutdown()
```

The [manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html) suggests to register a shutdown hook in order to be sure to have a right shutdown of the database